# JavaScript array contains "[object Window]" after filling it up with CSV file

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, csv, d3.js

So I'm working on a rich media application, it is some kind of Aaron Koblin style airplane flight visualization. Link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPv8psZsvIU
He's doing this in processing, but for school I need to do it in D3.js and much simpler.

What I'm trying to do is filling up an array with the data from met CSV file. Here is the code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var routeData = [];
    d3.csv("data/data2.csv", function(data) {
        routeData = data.map(function(d) {
            return [ toString(+d["Origin"]), toString(+d["Destination"])]; 
    });
    console.log(routeData[55])
  });
}
```

Now when I run this, I see this in the console:

```
["[object Window]", "[object Window]"]
```

All my array contain this "object Window", does anyone have a suggestion?

Many thanks

Comment: Why do you use `toString`?

Comment: how many rows/cols has your file?

Comment: Oh, well first it was NaN and found on stack overflow it could help.

Comment: you have a little error here: you're assigning routeData each time, so it has two elements. later you want element 55 when you only have 2. it's not the source of the error but it's worth to check

Comment: @LuisMasuelli it has 5367 rows.

Comment: I think you need just `return [ +d["Origin"], +d["Destination"]];`. They are strings already.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli I have got 5367 arrays, I just called the 55th element so I don't have a big list of arrays in my console and the number 55 is just random.

Comment: yes, but you're doing `routeData =` instead of `routeData.push()`. routeData will hold finally only two elements, instead of 5367.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff that is what I originally did but then I get "NaN" values in my arrays

Comment: @LuisMasuelli I tried .push already, it has the same effect.

Comment: So what is in your CSV? Is it actually numbers or strings? If strings, you don't need the `+`.

Comment: Indeed only string, that did it for the first value! Thanks for that! But the second value (which is also a string) is now "undefined".

Comment: Can you show us an example of your CSV?